# How do I check if string contains a list of signs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hava a list of sings:

```
var sings = [",",".",":","!","?"]
```

How do I check if a word contains one of these signs and return it?

For example:

```
"But,"

return ","

"Finished."

return "."

"Questions?"

return "?"
```

Comment: You're looking for regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve that with a regular expression:

```js
function match(input) {
  var regex = /([,\.\:!\?])/;
  var matches = input.match(regex);
  return matches ? matches[0] : false;
}

console.log(match("foo?"));   // "?"
console.log(match("bar."));   // "."
console.log(match("foobar")); // false
```

Comment: Beat me too that almost exact function :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is example function

```
var checkSigns = function(str) {
    var signs = [",",".",":","!","?"];

    for (var i = 0; i < signs.length; i++) {
        if (str.indexOf[signs[i]] !== -1) {
            return signs[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` and `indexOf()` and return array of signs that are found in string.

```js
var signs = [",",".",":","!","?"];
function check(str, arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(e) {
    return str.indexOf(e) != -1
  })
}

console.log(check("But,", signs))
console.log(check("Finished.", signs))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this prototype `str.hasSign();` return `sign` if contains or `false` if not.

```js
String.prototype.hasSigns = function() {
  var signs = [",", ".", ":", "!", "?"];
  for (var i = 0; i < signs.length; i++) {
    if (this.indexOf(signs[i]) > -1) return signs[i];
  }
  return false;
}

console.log("football, basketball".hasSigns());

console.log("1-3".hasSigns());

console.log("Good!".hasSigns());
```